# How can i group an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this

var cars = [
    {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }, {
        'make': 'kia',
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    },
];

i want to use reduce function to group it as follow

```
var cars = {
0: [
    {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    },
],

1: [
    {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }
],

2: [
    {
        'make': 'Kia',
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Please do some research yourself first and attempt to write the code you need. Then, if there is a problem with the code you've written, come back here, post the relevant code (preferably as a Stack Snippet) and people will be able to help you with your specific problem. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, your intention is to group items by `make`. In this case, you may do something, like:

```js
const src = [{ 'make': 'audi', 'model': 'r8', 'year': '2012' }, { 'make': 'audi', 'model': 'rs5', 'year': '2013' }, { 'make': 'ford', 'model': 'mustang', 'year': '2012' }, { 'make': 'ford', 'model': 'fusion', 'year': '2015' }, { 'make': 'kia', 'model': 'optima', 'year': '2012' }],

     {...result} = Object.values(src.reduce((r,e) => 
        (r[e.make] = r[e.make]||[], r[e.make].push(e), r), {}))
     
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
const makes = new Set(cars.map(c => c.make));

const result = Array.from(makes).reduce((acc, make, index) => {
    acc[index] = cars.filter(c => c.make === make);
    return acc;
}, {});
```

`result` should contain the data in the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cars = [ { 'make': 'audi', 'model': 'r8', 'year': '2012' }, { 'make': 'audi', 'model': 'rs5', 'year': '2013' }, { 'make': 'ford', 'model': 'mustang', 'year': '2012' }, { 'make': 'ford', 'model': 'fusion', 'year': '2015' }, { 'make': 'kia', 'model': 'optima', 'year': '2012' } ]

let uniqueValToKeyMap = {};
let keys = 0;
let finalObj = cars.reduce((obj,currVal = {} ,currIndex,arr)=>{
  const {make,model,year} = currVal;
  const isKeyAvailableForMake = uniqueValToKeyMap[make]>=0;
  if(!isKeyAvailableForMake){
    uniqueValToKeyMap[make] = keys++;
  }
  const availableModels = obj[uniqueValToKeyMap[make]];
  if(availableModels){
    obj[uniqueValToKeyMap[make]].push({make,model,year});
  }else{
    obj[uniqueValToKeyMap[make]] = [{make,model,year}]
  }
  return obj
},{})

console.log(finalObj);
```